# Microsoft Graph API PUT OneDrive/SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, put

Trying to post a file to a subfolder of the Shared Documents folder.  I thought I had the correct syntax down, but I keep getting StatusCode 400 Bad Request.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,495435b4-60c3-49b7-8f6e-1d262a120ae5,0fad9f67-35a8-4c0b-892e-113084058c0a/drives/b!tDVUScNgt0mPbh0mKhIK5WefrQ-oNQtMiS4RMIQFjAqJk9Tt237bQYC9yEkyNOr6/items/01JDP7KXJ7ZSCYHUJC7BFJW2X6BTR4Z4JH:/filename.xlsx:/content
```

where "filename" is the actual filename.

I know a GET to the following lists the subfolder:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,495435b4-60c3-49b7-8f6e-1d262a120ae5,0fad9f67-35a8-4c0b-892e-113084058c0a/drives/b!tDVUScNgt0mPbh0mKhIK5WefrQ-oNQtMiS4RMIQFjAqJk9Tt237bQYC9yEkyNOr6/items/01JDP7KXJ7ZSCYHUJC7BFJW2X6BTR4Z4JH
```

Request is going out as:

```
{Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,495435b4-60c3-49b7-8f6e-1d262a120ae5,0fad9f67-35a8-4c0b-892e-113084058c0a/drives/b!tDVUScNgt0mPbh0mKhIK5WefrQ-oNQtMiS4RMIQFjAqJk9Tt237bQYC9yEkyNOr6/items/01JDP7KXJ7ZSCYHUJC7BFJW2X6BTR4Z4JH:/', Version: 2.0, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub...BXS_cSg1CcZHj5Q
}}
```

Seems like it is dropping part of the request to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com,495435b4-60c3-49b7-8f6e-1d262a120ae5,0fad9f67-35a8-4c0b-892e-113084058c0a/drives and https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com/drives will return the same results, we prefer the second one.

I have never sucessful run the following API:

```
/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

But based on my test, the following API works well:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Test/Test1.txt:/content
```

or

```
/v1.0/me/drives/driveid/root:/Test/Test1.txt:/content
```

Comment: I'm assuming the /Test/ is the subfolder?

Comment: Yes, Test is a subfolder. I am not sure why the items/item-id doesn't work.

Comment: I tried both of those links above in Graph Explorer, but they do put me in different places.  The top one puts me in the subsite Shared Documents folder where the other puts me at the company Shared Documents folder.

Comment: No offical docs, but the drive and /dirves/driveid maybe pointed position by design, just my guess. We need to do more test on this and submit the corresponding feedback to the Product Group(PG) if needed.